# Using CsvHelper with a Stream

Tags: csv, stream, streamreader, blazor, csvhelper

I'm trying to use CsvHelper to read in a CSV file and create a DataTable from it. The first row will be a header record providing column names, but other than that, the structure of the file is unknown. If I use the following code (taken from an example by the author of CsvHelper), it works.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    // Do any configuration to `CsvReader` before creating CsvDataReader.
    using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
    {        
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
}
```

However, if I use an alternate constructor for the StreamReader that takes a Stream as a parameter instead of a file path, then the creation of the CsvDataReader fails with an error message of "Synchronous reads are not supported."

I've tried a few other methods of CsvHelper in attempts to handle the data differently, but I keep running into the same error any time that the StreamReader is created by passing in a Stream rather than a file path. I'm starting to wonder whether the real issue lies with the implementation of StreamReader or with CsvHelper. Passing in a Stream makes much more sense in my situation (a Blazor Server app). Any ideas?

EDIT:

I believe David Specht is correct in that there is something unique about the particular stream I was using. In further testing, I've found that some strings **do** work. In the situation where I have the error, I am reading the stream from Steve Sanderson's BlazorInputFile component (on GitHub) using the IFileListEntry.Data stream interface. I suspect that there is something in its implementation that causes the error I'm getting. If that's the case, then a workaround would be helpful. (Maybe creating one stream from another to switch between asynchronous and synchronous streams? Not sure how to do that yet, but I'm going to give it a shot.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As David Specht pointed out in his answer, and as indicated in my edit to the original question, it **does** work with some Streams. Something in the implementation of the stream, `file.Data`, in the example below doesn't work well with `CsvHelper`, causing the "Synchronous reads are not supported" error. This particular stream is an instance `IFileListEntry.Data` from the `BlazorInputFile` component created by Steve Sanderson and available on GitHub. (All in all, this component seems to work quite well keeping in mind that I'm using version *0.1.0-preview-00002* so thanks, Steve!)

By copying the stream to a new stream using `Stream.CopyToAsync()` the problem goes away. One caveat to keep in mind is that, after this function executes, both the input and output streams will be positioned at the end of the stream. The stream that will be used to create the `CsvReader` must be set back to the beginning in order for the `CsvDataReader` constructor to work properly. If this is not done, there will be a "No header record was found" error.

The following example works for me and will hopefully help someone else!

```
using (var stream2 = new MemoryStream())
{
    await file.Data.CopyToAsync(stream2);   // although file.Data is itself a stream, using it directly causes "synchronous reads are not supported" errors below.
    stream2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);      // at the end of the copy method, we are at the end of both the input and output stream and need to reset the one we want to work with.
    var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream2);

    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv)) // error happens here when "file.Data" is used as the stream: "Synchronous reads are not supported"
                                                // error happens here when the stream isn't reset to the beginning: "No header record was found"
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the first solution I found that actually solved my issue. I didn't use CsvDataReader but the first bit especially the `.Seek` helped a ton since I was getting that "No header record was found" error!

Comment: It should be noted that CsvHelper has an issue (open at the time of this writing) that indicates that, even if you call one of the async-read methods, under certain conditions it can still do a synchronous read.  See https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1400  @Zac mentions this below, but I wanted to call it out.

Comment: Steve's "prototype" `BlazorInputFile` has now been replaced by the official `InputFile` component, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0  The official component doesn't have the `ReadAllAsync` extension mentioned by Zac, as far as I can see, but we can view its source here: https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile/blob/master/BlazorInputFile/FileListEntryExtensions.cs  And what we see closely correlates to your answer here, so I have faith in your answer.  It seems to be the most practical solution to the CsvHelper problem.

Comment: An irony is that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0 states: "Avoid reading the incoming file stream directly into memory. For example, don't copy file bytes into a MemoryStream or read as a byte array. These approaches can result in performance and security problems, especially in Blazor Server." but I'm ok with doing so because I'm using Blazor WebAssembly, and I don't let the file size be too large.

Comment: @BellarmineHead I am using Blazor Server and MSDN documentation warning of reading files directly to memory is considered how can i read the files using csvHelper Any examples?

Comment: BlazorInputFile  repository is not more maintained as far as i can see from github So will it be a good idea to use that ? Or is there any recommended alternatives available?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue with the BlazorInputFile and CsvReader. I looked in the code for BlazorInputFile and you can see where Steve has it throw an error if you synchronously read the stream. Additionally, there are a couple of open items and discussions in CsvReader's git that seems related to why it's not allowed in BlazorInputFile. [CsvParser's ReadAsync can read stream synchronously](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1400) and [improve async/await performance](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1199) On the other hand, there's an extension method, ReadAllAsync, added to IFileListEntry that returns an async MemoryStream. You just call that when you're creating your StreamReader.

Note:

1. With the latest version of CsvReader, you must specify the CultureInfo parameter.
2. I'm using this successfully with the csv mapped to an IList not a DataTable so you still might run into an issue but it should work.

```
            using var stream = new StreamReader(await file.ReadAllAsync());
            using var csv = new CsvReader(stream, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            using var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
```

Comment: Are you managing to read file contents  uploaded from blazor by without saving the file first?  Can you add bit more sections to this answer ? like file.ReadAllAsync() Is it the actula uploaded file or file saved to some path?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the stream you are using needs to be read asynchronously?  The following works for me.

```cs
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv");
var response = request.GetResponse();

using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(stream)))
{
    using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, I suspect you're right about that. In further testing I found that some streams do work. See my edit above that provides more information. If that's the case, then I'll need a workaround of some sort.