# Read Excel saved to a file location from Blazor Server project using csvHelper

Tags: c#, excel, blazor-server-side, csvhelper

Following is my blazor server side project page to upload an excel file to server and process the file using CsvHelper

```
@page "/contact/import"
@using System.Data
@using System.IO
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 
@inject IWebHostEnvironment Environment

<h1>Upload Data</h1>

<p>This component   uploads data from Excel.</p>
 
<InputFile OnChange="@LoadFiles"  />

<MudButton HtmlTag="label"
           Variant="Variant.Filled"
           Color="Color.Primary"
           StartIcon="@Icons.Filled.CloudUpload"
           for="fileInput">
    Upload Files
</MudButton>
  
@code {
  
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    }

    private async Task LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {  
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#upload-files-to-a-server
            long maxFileSize =  1024 * 1024 * 15; //15 MB            
            foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(1))
            {
                string rootpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "FileUploads");

                var trustedFileNameForFileStorage = file.Name; //Path.GetRandomFileName();
                var path = Path.Combine(rootpath,
                        trustedFileNameForFileStorage);
                await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
                await file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize).CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            
        } 
    }
}
```

This code will save the file to the folder FileUploads

I am using CSVHelper to read the contents of excel file uploaded by the user , But not finding a way to read from a file saved from the specific location

From this url
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#upload-files-to-a-server
I can see that

> Avoid reading the incoming file stream directly into memory. For
> example, don't copy file bytes into a MemoryStream or read as a byte
> array. These approaches can result in performance and security
> problems, especially in Blazor Server. Instead, consider copying file
> bytes to an external store, such as a blob or a file on disk. If you
> need access to a Stream that represents the file's bytes, use
> IBrowserFile.OpenReadStream.

This is the reason why i am thinking of saving file first to a location and then read from the file

But not finding a way to copy the file contents to a stream and then CsvHelper can use the stream to convert to a Data Table like in csvHelper example

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv")) // How can i read from the file which is just saved!
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
   
}
```

Or is it really necessary to save the file or any safe ways available to read the contents of excel to csvHelper

Found one more helpful thread [Using CsvHelper with a Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829430/using-csvhelper-with-a-stream) but looks like the solution is using some other plugins

Comment: CsvHelper doesn't work with Excel files. A CSV file is a text file with fields separated by commas - `A,5.4,Potato`. `xlsx` files are ZIP files containing well-formed XML files.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it does if you have CsvHelper.Excel and ClosedXml installed.. The difficulty with the approach in Blazor is that while a CSV is good for streaming, I don't think anything exists that can stream a binary excel file (either format) however conceptually possible it might be, so processing them is a case of buffering the file somewhere, especially if theyre large.. I limit my BSS code to 1 Mb file size if it's accepting an XLSX otherwise the memory usage goes through the roof with CSVH/CSVH.E. Gigabytes of CSV are fine for streaming in via an async read though

Comment: @CaiusJard Indeed, most XLSX readers are very memory inefficient. Check out my Sylvan.Data.Excel library which uses orders of magnitude less memory than the competitors: https://github.com/MarkPflug/Benchmarks/blob/main/docs/ExcelBenchmarks.md

Comment: @markpflug can it do an async read from the stream supplying the xls[x]?

Comment: @CaiusJard Not currently, no. Async is on the short list of features I intend to add though. Are you aware of any Excel library that does support async currently?

Comment: I haven't thus far come across one; for the Blazor stuff where I had to read the stream async I CopyToAsync'd it to a memorystream and then used CsvHelper+.Excel extension/closedxml to read it sync, but it wasn;t a delightful experience. It didn't matter so much because I had only a few files over 1 gb to import, so I re-saved them as a CSV which I could stream async. The ongoing task is smaller files of < 1mb, which only jumps the memory use of the server up by about 250mb when imported! Planning on taking a look at sylvan to see how that changes

Comment: @CaiusJard ReadAsync into a MemoryStream is what I'd recommend for people who need async currently. I actually have async implemented for the .xls format, but since I expose everything (.xls, .xlsx, .xlsb) through the same API, I can't support it until all three are there. .xlsx is probably the hardest to add without killing performance, but I have a strategy that I think will work. Just need to find time to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I maintain an Excel data reader library that you might have more luck with: [Sylvan.Data.Excel](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan.Data.Excel). It is open source, MIT licensed, targets netstandard 2.0 or 2.1 (which supports all .NET core versions) and has no other dependencies.  It can be used with either a file path or you can provide it a stream.

It supports the three most widely used Excel formats `.xlsx`, `.xslb`, and `.xls`. It is the [fastest and most memory efficient Excel library for .NET](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Benchmarks/blob/main/docs/ExcelBenchmarks.md) (by a very wide margin in some cases). The API implements DbDataReader, so it should feel familiar for anyone who has used the ADO.NET APIs.

```
using Sylvan.Data.Excel;

var reader = ExcelDataReader.Create("path/to/file.xlsx");
// alternately you can provide a stream and a file type
//var reader = ExcelDataReader.Create(stream, ExcelWorkbookType.ExcelXml);

do // iterate sheets
{ 
    var sheet = reader.WorksheetName;
    // iterate rows in the file
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var value = reader.GetString(i);
        }
    }
} while (reader.NextResult());
```