# Stream CopyToAsync never returns

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, signalr, blazor

Trying to parse a csv file from a memory stream with csvhelper and since I'm using a stream I can't use a synchronous read. Originally I used the GetRecordsAsync method, but it would hang interminably. I figured it was an issue with the package and so decided to follow the advice of a similar post: [Using CsvHelper with a Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829430/using-csvhelper-with-a-stream). However now it hangs on the `stream.CopyToAsync(newstream)` method. Furthermore signal R gives the following (unhelpful) error:

`Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection: Warning: The connection FDF6ub9XgExRg_etyA9NSgee127c661 has a long running application logic that prevents the connection from complete.`

The csv file itself is 26 rows and 13kb, so it's not like it's doing some massive operation.

code is pretty much identical to that other post:

```
using (var newStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);   // hangs here and never returns. signalR disconnects, no Exceptions
    stream2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  
    ...
 }
```

So what's the deal is there some sort of configuration for SignalR I missed?

Comment: `stream.CopyToAsync` won't complete if the input stream never closes.  If you read from a `NetworkStream` and the remote server never closes the connection, `CopyToAsync` will never complete. What is `stream`, where does it come from? And what's the point of copying its contents into a `MemoryStream`? As for `since I'm using a stream I can't use a synchronous read.` that's simply wrong: CsvHelper always reads from streams. This doesn't affect whether you can use blocking operations or not

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock somewhere. Considering you are using `async` it's probably a sync-over-async deadlock: somewhere in your code you have `.Result` or `.Wait` and it should have `await` instead

Comment: As for the linked question, the problem was caused because the OP used an obsolete experimental *Blazor WASM* component, not an actual .NET stream

Comment: yep I'm in the middle of trying something but I believe the issue is spelled out in these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server. Will update when I confirm it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Blazor's input file. Can't read directly from it need to save as a file somewhere and then stream it from that path. See the link in the comments above.